# Enable Windows Phone 7.8? VS 2010?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I downloaded [Windows Phone SDK update for Windows Phone 7.8](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=36474) and installed it. I however don't see these 2 new emulators they are talking about. Do I have to do something to get them.

I am on a windows 8 box, with both VS 2010 and Vs 2012 on it and neither show these emulators for 7.8. I just get to choose 7.0 and 7.1.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it should look like after installing WP 7.8 SDK update.

[image]

Now, show us how it looks like in your VS. So that your problem is clearly understood.

Did you install, [WP 7.1.1 Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29233) before installing 7.8 update ?

And you said, its showing 7.0 and 7.1 ? where is it showing ? Microsoft stopped support for 7.0 devices few months back.

Note: Though this is not a real answer, I added it as an answer inorder to add the screen shot. Update your question with more details.

Comment: Ok. I am now seeing those emulators(before I did not). I was kinda shocked when my app said it supported(in the app store) 7.5 and nothing about 7.8. I don't remember installing 7.1.1 I just installed the 7.0 sdk before hand. I updated my post with a screenshot of 7.0.

Comment: Though you install 7.8 it still shows 7.0 and 7.1 only, Thats not a problem. So now your problem is solved right ??

Comment: So do I always choose 7.1 and then run through the 7.8 emulator?

Comment: Yes of course. Except for the Live tiles, actually there is not much difference in the 7.1 and 7.8 SDK's. So no need to bother much about it